# Is there a way to tweak this formula to make this work, even if the name doesn't 100% match? If so, how?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use a script to automatically set up conditional formatting to highlight a specific set of names in a Google Sheet. The data comes from a Google Form where people enter their own name. The conditional formatting is triggered if both first and last names match the listed entries (in the example below, **Harry Potter* and *Ron Weasley*).

The script coding looks like this:

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied('=OR(AND($D7="Potter",$E7="Harry"),AND($D7="Weasley",$E7="Ron"))')
```

**Problem:** If the person hits the spacebar after their name, or types *Ronald* instead of *Ron* or the like, then the highlighting doesn't work. I know I can't make it work if they make a typo entering either half of their name. I would, though, like it to still work if they hit the spacebar or don't abbreviate, etc. So, I want it to work as long as the specified text string is present.

**Question: Is there a way to tweak this formula to make this work, even if the name doesn't 100% match? If so, how?**

Comment: Use `REGEXMATCH`

Comment: What happens if you have a Ronald and a Ronda, And the user types Ron?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, TheWizEd, since it's partially an AND function. In the example above, it would only highlight the user's entry of *Ron* if the last name was also *Weasley*, and the list of names is not such that I have both a Ronald and Ronda Weasley. There's only going to be 20 or so names that it will look for in the entire dataset.

Comment: TheMaster, I wouldn't think REGEXMATCH does the trick,  because it has to match two columns of data to trigger. So, it's only going to highlight *Ron* if the last name is *Weasley*. If it's *Ron*, but the last name field is *Burgundy*, it won't highlight.

Comment: Use the same logic in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of strict comparison `=`, use `REGEXMATCH`.

For eg,

> If the person hits the spacebar after their name, or types Ronald instead of Ron or the like,

Change

```
$E7="Ron"
```

to

```
REGEXMATCH($E7,"Ron.*")
```

- `.` Any character(like space or `ald`)
- `*`  Previous regex repeated zero to unlimited times

See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

`REGEXMATCH` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` just like `=` does.